# How did Feedly implemented custom pagecontrol for its app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

Feedly for iPhone comes with cool design especially its custom pagecontrol(scrollbar?) placed on the top.

I'm developing an app for iPhone, and to use spaces efficiently as much as it's possible I'm trying to find a way to implement custom pagecontrol like Feedly. I actually think it's possible the app is made with HTML5 and CSS? Although I am not sure. I found some custom opensourced pagecontrol frameworks, but they're to do with something else such as dots' colors either sizes.

Here's example image link to Feedly for iOS https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf595.jpg

Although this is an iPad version, basically iPhone one is the same. You see the green bar just below the status bar, if you slide pages the colored bar scrolls. It's much more like scrollbar.

Thanks.

- Okay, so I unarchived the app and it turned out it's mainly made with HTMLs and converted using PhoneGap. I'm not going to use HTML in my app, my journey still goes on...

Comment: Before starting coding, gave a shot for searching a bit more and I found this: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/sliderpagecontrol 
Not the same but looks similar, it might make it easier. Just to share. It's so nice many developers are sharing cool libraries...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting all contents into an UIWebView (implementing in HTML & CSS) is generally a bad idea performance wise.

What Feedly seems to do is use an `UIScrollView`.
The ScrollView sends several events including when it's moved and tapped.

They then update the green scroll bar on top whenever the ScrollView is moved.
Likely, they will also load the actual contents within the ScrollView as the user approaches their position to conserve memory.

You can implement something like this yourself in a few days of coding work.

(Disclaimer: This is just how I would implement what you showed. How it is actually done - only Feedly knows.)

Comment: I see... That sounds actually nice, I give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: If you like the answer, don't forget to upvote and accept. It keeps the good answers coming.

Comment: Sorry about that. Clicked checkmark and up-arrow, but seems I don't have enough reputation to vote up..